# Test the convergence of the series...

Tags: sequences-and-series

So, the series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^k}$$
What I did is:
$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^k}*\frac{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{2}{n^k(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n})}$$
I'm not sure what to do next, which criteria should I use?

Comment: What is $\;k\;$ ?

Comment: Are you supposed to find values of $k$ for which the series will converge?

Comment: so $a_n\sim n^{-(k+\frac 12)}$ hence $a_n$ is convegent if and only if $\cdots$

Comment: you can do limit comparison with  $\frac 1{n^{k+1/2}}$

Comment: k is probably a constant for which I have to test the convergence in different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

$$\frac{1}{2n^{k+1/2}} < a_n < \frac{2}{n^{k+1/2}}$$

for all $n \ge 1$. Thus $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-(k+1/2)}$ converges. Now use the $p$-test.

Remark: To get the lower bound $\frac{1}{2n^{k + 1/2}} < a_n$, consider that 
$$\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n} <2\sqrt{n+2} < 2\sqrt{n + 3n} = 2\sqrt{4n} = 4\sqrt{n}.$$

This implies $a_n > \frac{2}{n^k(4\sqrt{n})} = \frac{1}{2n^{k+1/2}}$.

Comment: Your first expression, shouldn't it be > instead of <?

Comment: No. I gave an explanation in the remark.

Comment: I understand most of it, but still find some things unclear. How did you get the upper bound and do you need both bounds to test the convergence?

Comment: To get the upper bound, use the fact $\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n} > \sqrt{n}$ to get $a_n < \frac{2}{n^k\sqrt{n}} = \frac{2}{n^{k+1/2}}$. I put both bounds for $a_n$ so that you may deduce from the comparison test that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-(k+1/2)}$ converges.

Comment: Do we need the lower bound for comparison test, or we can deduce that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the upper bound converges?

Comment: We need both bounds. If $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-(k+1/2)}$ converges, then since $0 < a_n < 2n^{-(k+1/2)}$ for all $n$, direct comparison shows $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges. On the other hand, if $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-(k+1/2)}$ diverges, then since $a_n > 0.5n^{-(k+1/2)}$ for all $n$, direct comparison shows $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ diverges. Hence $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-(k+1/2)}$ converges.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: One more question, if we didn't have a lower bound, what would it mean? I mean, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-(k+\frac{1}{2})}$ diverges, what happens with our series when we didn't specify a lower bound?

Comment: All it means is you don't have enough information to determine whether of not $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}\sim 2\sqrt{n}$ and use the comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac1{n^k(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt n)}\le\frac1{n^k\cdot2\sqrt n}=\frac12\frac1{n^{k+\frac12}}$$